# Parsing JSON array for certain strings in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I'm trying to get certain strings from a website but having difficulty. This is the array (blocking out certain values)

```
{
    "ts": 1468156734285,
    "inbox": "email",
    "created": 302,
    "expire_in": 86098,
    "last_eml": 1468156432,
    "emls": [{
        "eml": "this is the email id",
        "eml_hash": "email hash",
        "eml_destroy_hash": "3319b480",
        "subject": "Welcome to your new temporary inbox",
        "from_address": "welcome@mytemp.email",
        "from_name": "welcome",
        "status": "read",
        "received": 302,
        "size": 0
     }]
}
```

In the 'emls' array, I'm trying to get 'eml' and 'eml_hash' as a python string. This is my code so far:

```
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
print data
emal = data['emls']
eml_hash = data['eml_hash']
```

But it can't find these values

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 40, in <module>
emal= data['eml']
```

KeyError: 'eml'
Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `print data`? And are you this is the code you are running? in your code `emal = data['emls']` but in the error `emal = data['eml']`

Comment: {u'created': 0, u'emls': [{u'status': u'unread', u'received': 0, u'from_name': u'welcome', u'from_address': u'welcome@mytemp.email', u'eml': u'5782524e96af80bf583b57a1', u'eml_destroy_hash': u'65b15f22', u'eml_hash': u'1c759d60', u'size': 0, u'subject': u'Welcome to your new temporary inbox'}], u'last_eml': 1468158543, u'ts': 1468158542729L, u'inbox': u'xkp@g.tiv.cc', u'expire_in': 86400}

Comment: Sorry, had been modifying code.
emal = data['eml'] prints the error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 40, in <module>
    emal= data['eml']
    KeyError: 'eml'
emls prints:
    [{u'status': u'unread', u'received': 0, u'from_name': u'welcome', u'from_address': u'welcome@mytemp.email', u'eml': u'5782531d96af80bf583b57d4', u'eml_destroy_hash': u'4a88e4a2', u'eml_hash': u'82d5112f', u'size': 0, u'subject': u'Welcome to your new temporary inbox'}]

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
print data
emls = data['emls'] # emls = [{'status': 'unread','received': 0,...}]
```

Makes `emls` equal the list with a dictionary inside. So you need to take the first (0th) item of that list. Then you can use the keys `eml` and `eml_hash`.

```
eml = emls[0]['eml']
eml_hash = emls[0]['eml_hash]
```

If `emls` has more than one email in, simply loop over it:

```
eml = [] # List of all eml, email IDs.
eml_hash = [] # list of all eml_has, email hashes

for email in emls:
    eml += [email['eml]]
    eml_hash = [email['eml_hash']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty straightforward, given that `data` is the dictionary you provided:

```
data = {
"ts": 1468156734285,
"inbox": "email",
"created": 302,
"expire_in": 86098,
"last_eml": 1468156432,
"emls": [{
    "eml": "this is the email id",
    "eml_hash": "email hash",
    "eml_destroy_hash": "3319b480",
    "subject": "Welcome to your new temporary inbox",
    "from_address": "welcome@mytemp.email",
    "from_name": "welcome",
    "status": "read",
    "received": 302,
    "size": 0
}]}

for email in data['emls']:
    print(email['eml'])
    print(email['eml_hash'])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is actually indexing the root of the dictionary, `data`, again. Therefore, you wouldn't get the expected output:

```
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
print data
emal = data['emls']
# You should not be indexing data again. Note that emls is a list too.
eml_hash = data['eml_hash']
```

So your code would be:

```
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
print data
eml = data['emls']
eml_hash = data['emls'][0]['eml_hash']
```

Or:

```
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
print data
eml = data['emls']
eml_hash = eml[0]['eml_hash']
```

Outputs:

```
>>> eml
[{u'status': u'read', u'received': 302, u'from_name': u'welcome', u'from_address': u'welcome@mytemp.email', u'eml': u'this is the email id', u'eml_destroy_hash': u'3319b480', u'eml_hash': u'email hash', u'size': 0, u'subject': u'Welcome to your new temporary inbox'}]
>>> eml_hash
u'email hash'
```